# how to replace a method name based on condition in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

is there any way to just replace a method name with another method name based on conditions in swift2.2?

example:

```
 if(self.RecivedString == "varMethod"){
     self.routes.varMethod(postData, andCompletionHandler: { (response, error) in
                if(error.length == 0){
                    if(response.valueForKey("status") as! NSInteger == 1){

                        self.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(SubmitViewController.navigateToSubmissionViewController), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
                    }else{
                        self.showalert(response.valueForKey("msg") as! String)
                    }


                }else{
                    self.showalert(error as String)
                }
            })


  }
```

in the above example i want to replace self.routes.varMethod name with other self.routes.varMethodNew name base on conditions.

Comment: I don't think you can replace one method, But to achieve your goal you can create one new method (i.e varMethodNew) and based on your requirement and call the required method based on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *replace a method name with another method name*, but you can have a closure variable to hold a reference to the methods.

Assuming you have two classes like this:

```
class Routes {
    typealias CompletionHandler = ([String: AnyObject], NSError?)->Void
    func varMethod(data: NSData, andCompletionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
        //...
    }
    func varMethodNew(data: NSData, andCompletionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
        //...
    }
}

class SubmitViewController: UIViewController {
    var routes: Routes = Routes()
    var recievedString: String?
    func showAlert(message: String) {/*...*/}
    func navigateToSubmissionViewController() {/*...*/}
    //...
}
```

You can write some method using the closure variable in your `SubmitViewController` as:

```
func someMethod(postData: NSData) {
    //Declare a closure variable
    let theMethod: (NSData, andCompletionHandler: Routes.CompletionHandler)->Void //<-Make this match to `varMethod` and `varMethodNew`.
    if self.recievedString == "varMethod" {
        theMethod = self.routes.varMethod
    } else {
        theMethod = self.routes.varMethodNew
    }
    //And call it
    theMethod(postData, andCompletionHandler: { response, error in
        if error == nil {
            if response["status"] as! Int == 1 {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.navigateToSubmissionViewController()
                }
            } else {
                self.showAlert(response["msg"] as! String)
            }
        } else {
            self.showAlert(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

---

But in your case, you can define the completion handler as a closure variable:

```
func someOtherMethod(postData: NSData) {
    //Declare a closure variable
    let completionHandler: Routes.CompletionHandler = { response, error in
        if error == nil {
            if response["status"] as! Int == 1 {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.navigateToSubmissionViewController()
                }
            } else {
                self.showAlert(response["msg"] as! String)
            }
        } else {
            self.showAlert(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    //And use it
    if self.recievedString == "varMethod" {
        self.routes.varMethod(postData, andCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
    } else {
        self.routes.varMethodNew(postData, andCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```